# A circle being drawn when hover over div

Tags: jquery, css, hover, geometry

I've looked for this question, I found some answers but it's not really what I need.

I'm not really experienced with jquery, but I already made the hover function! When I hover over the div, it will resize.
What I want to add to this effect is: on the same hover, a circle will be drawn around an image.

I've already seen answers where people add a box-radius. But what I'm looking for is that you actually see the circle being drawn. 
An example at 0:49 seconds (its a bit random but this video shows the effect I need):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=jCdNnaTzItM#t=45s

I hope this is possible!

my code:

```
$('li#balk1').hover(
    function(){ $(".ad").css('transform', 'scale(1.2)'); },
    function(){ $(".ad").css('transform', 'scale(1)'); } 
);
```

There should be a circle around ".ad"

Comment: You can't really do this sort of thing in HTML, that isn't how the DOM works. You'd have an easier time just fading in a circle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I will just do that as a temporary solution. I've seen some pretty crazy stuff being done with jquery :p

Comment: jQuery is not "crazy", and it's not magic. It just manipulates DOM elements in a slightly more sane way than directly accessing the DOM API. It can't be used to draw arbitrary things. If you're looking to *draw* stuff, jQuery isn't going to be useful.

Comment: Yeah thats right.
I think it shouldn't be "drawn", what about a line being filled?
http://buildinternet.com/2009/06/animate-image-filling-up-using-jquery/

Comment: I think it is possible, you only need to build some kind of workaround and think a bit out of the box. How I would do it: Add canvas to dom with position: absolute (or relative, depends on your structure), set width to $('li#balk1').outerWidth() + 20, height to $('li#balk1').outerHeight() + 20, set left and top as intended. Now you can build a small function to draw a rectangle or cycle inside this canvas with the intended measurements and color. Do not forget to handle that the mouse enters the canvas and leaves the element as soon as you show the canvas.

Comment: Forgot to mention: My solution would possibly need HTML5 to work (as all modern browsers do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this [Codepen (link)](http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/upjDy) or it's also available as a [gist (link)](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/d9995b8f12e23063f17c)

Using a SVG stroke attributes we animate an SVG line generated with a rand calculated imperfect bezier curve.  I think this should be pretty close what you were looking for.

*jQuery and D3 dependencies*

```
<style>
path.ln {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: #999;
    fill: none;
    vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: dash 4s cubic-bezier(0.45,0.3,0.35,0.3);
    -moz-animation:dash 4s cubic-bezier(0.45,0.3,0.35,0.3);
    -o-animation:dash 4s cubic-bezier(0.45,0.3,0.35,0.3);
    animation:dash 4s cubic-bezier(0.45,0.3,0.35,0.3);
}

@keyframes dash {
    to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
</style>

<script>
function path(min_rad_delta,max_rad_delta, el_min, el_max, el_min_delta,el_max_delta) {
    var d = Math.sqrt( 0.5 * 0.5 + 1 * 1 ), r = 1; //returns the square root of a number
    var el = (el_min + Math.random() * (el_max - el_min)) * Math.PI / 180;
    var path = 'M' + [r * Math.sin(el), r * Math.cos(el)] + ' C' + [d * r * Math.sin(el + Math.LN2), d * r * Math.cos(el + Math.LOG10E)];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        el += Math.PI / 2 * (1 + el_min_delta + Math.random() * (el_max_delta - el_min_delta));
        r *= (1 + min_rad_delta + Math.random()*(max_rad_delta - min_rad_delta));
        path += ' ' + (i?'S':'') + [d * r * Math.sin(el - 0.45), d * r * Math.cos(el - 0.45)];
        path += ' ' + [r * Math.sin(el), r * Math.cos(el)];
    }
    return path;
}

function cX(lambda_min, lambda_max, el_min, el_max) {
    var el = (el_min + Math.random()*(el_max - el_min));
    return 'rotate(' + el + ') ' + 'scale(1, ' + (lambda_min + Math.random()*(lambda_max - lambda_min)) + ')'+ 'rotate(' + (-el) + ')';
}
</script>

<svg id="circle" width="50%" height="75%" viewBox='-1.5 -1.5 3 3'></svg>

<script>
d3.selectAll( 'svg' )
    .append( 'path' )
    .classed( 'ln', true)
    .attr( 'd', path(-0.1,0, 0,360, 0,0.2 ))
    .attr( 'transform', cX( 0.6, 0.8, 0, 360 ));
setTimeout(function() { location = '' } ,5000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, it turns out you can do this, I've thrown up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5tHC/281/) modifying [this](http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/07/20/animating-with-curves-in-jquery/) solution. I believe it relies on the use of the `tween` and `curve` plugins, which are explained in more detail in the second link.